# How to run multiple JMS clients supporting multiple vendors and versions within a single service?

Tags: apache-camel, mule, jms, websphere, esb

Looking to create a service composed of JMS clients that support multiple JMS vendors and JMS versions.  Ideally running in a single service instance/JVM.

Mule, Apache Camel, IBM Websphere MQ and the like have done something similar.  It's a feature available in ESB's, and I'm not keen on how they have architected multiple JMS clients running on a single platform.  They may or may not have built it out on a single service instance.

What sort of knowledge and tooling is out there that can help guide me in this quest?  Prefer JVM solutions.

For the three who closed due to "not about coding"... JMS, the "Java Message Service" is a Java messaging framework https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html ... the solution will certainly be code based.

Comment: There is already IBM MQ for this. Have you looked at it? It is not an ESB or anything like that.

Comment: Yes thank you.  I am building what you could call a competing product in that sense, so do not want to license from IBM.  This can be done easily with multiple services/processes running on the platform, but I'm considering ways to do it well from a single process.

Comment: Aha, sounds interesting and a lot of work ;)